# ASP.Net Core MVC client side validation: attributes do not display

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have built a simple .net Core MVC application.
I have an action that returns a ViewResult with a model:

```
public class Model {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2 {
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

And with an AbstractValidator:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Model>, ModelValidator>();

public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Model2.B)
       .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");

        RuleFor(x => x.A)
       .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    }
}
```

I have also included jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive with correct order.

My problem: When i add an input tag in HTML, data-val attributes are not generated for sub class.

```
@*Has data-val attributes*@
<div>
    <label asp-for="A"></label>
    <input asp-for="A" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="A" class="validation-error"></span>
</div>

@*Has no data-val attributes*@
<div>
    <label asp-for="Model2.B"></label>
    <input asp-for="Model2.B" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Model2.B" class="validation-error"></span>
</div>
```

What did i forget?

Answer (score 1):

You could try unobtrustive validation on your form, which will validate your nested object property (Model2.B). For more information on unobtrustive validation, see [this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/1111) So, the following is the code you should implement.

Add a javascript function that implements unobtrustive validation on your form:

```
 function submitForm(form) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    //form validation is evaluated here
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        //here your own code...
    }
    else {
        //here your own code...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call the above function in your in html form.

```
    <form onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
        //this part is for your own sake

        //button type should be submit 
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control text-white">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: When razor generate html then input of Model2B does not has data-val attributes, so validator always return true for it.

Comment: Yeah, but i updated the question. Require attribute is in a validator class not in property. It cause the problem. 

Your answer is correct if i have data-val attributes on input fields. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

FluentValidation not support properly nested class client validation.
Use ViewModel validation attributes instead of it.